# SQL Update all rows on new column with exists column data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've recently added a new column to one of our tables that needs to contain the date from another column + 365 days. Updating each record individually is not feasible and everything I have tried does not work. Mostly receiving this error:

*Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

My latest attempt to script this below.

```
UPDATE A SET A.enddate_dt = DATEADD(day,365,B.appdate_dt)
FROM cd.mhc_appdiscfee A 
    INNER JOIN cd.mhc_appdiscfee B ON B.uniqueid_c = A.uniqueid_c
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just remove the column and calculate the value on-the-fly in your select queries? Or use a trigger

Comment: What is the purpose of the JOIN?

Comment: The queries that are ran on this table are not created by me but by a third party that creates our software (yeah i know right). I have in fact created a trigger for all new values to the date automatically created when added to the table but that leaves me with all the existing data to change. As for the JOIN I copied that from another script here on stack exchange I believe it was meant to have the subquery find the one unique result and match it as the table is its own data source for the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a small sample where the function works OK. Mean something is wrong with your data.

[**SQL DEMO**](http://rextester.com/OXDJR98966)

But if you are using a single table, just use. (Im using int instead of dates in my sample)

```
UPDATE A SET A.[enddate_dt ] = DATEADD(day,365, A.[appdate_dt])
FROM Table1 A;
```

[image]

Comment: This guy is right. We are focusing on the smoke and mirrors of making this join work when in fact a join should never have even come into play.  This is a simple update statement on each row using one of the row's columns to set the value of another of the row's columns.  case closed

Comment: @CharlesMcIntosh Yes, I just saw `A, B` and tought they were different tables.

Comment: Well it seems my issue was all along the fact that I had created a trigger to  add the enddate_dt whenever the table was inserted or updated going forward. Having the trigger run side by side of the code which I had first tried which was very similar to yours and to Rich's code made any attempt to update the enddate_dt fail with the subquery error. Disabling the script and running either of the codes made it work. Selecting your answer as correct specifically because you took the most time to provide help.

Answer (score 1):

This is telling you that your unique id is not unique.  Also, will this data change after initial assignment?  If not you could use a computed column instead.

Comment: The data on the uniqueid_c field is indeed unique. I've tested it with a script very much like the one posted by Juan Carlos.

Comment: If it is unique on both tables then you will not get this message.  If this is a one to many relationship it is likely that the child table has duplicates and is the reason for the message.

Comment: I didnt realize the table were the same. Then you dont need JOIN check my answer

Answer (score 0):

TRY to see if those are really unique

```
SELECT A.uniqueid_c, COUNT(*)
FROM cd.mhc_appdiscfee A
GROUP BY A.uniqueid_c
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

And

```
SELECT B.uniqueid_c, COUNT(*)
FROM cd.mhc_appdiscfee B
GROUP BY B.uniqueid_c
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

**EDIT:**

Another test

```
 SELECT A.uniqueid_c,
        B.uniqueid_c,
        COUNT(*)
 FROM cd.mhc_appdiscfee A 
 INNER JOIN cd.mhc_appdiscfee B 
    ON B.uniqueid_c = A.uniqueid_c;
 GROUP BY A.uniqueid_c,
          B.uniqueid_c
```

Comment: Both of these return no results as did my initial script for testing if the field was indeed unique. This was my first thought when the queries I was running returned the too many values on subquery result.

Comment: Then maybe provide a small sample of both table where you can reproduce the error. try using sqlFiddle.com. I also include another test. but should the same.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here? Surely you can just do :

```
Update cd.mhc_appdiscfee set enddate_dt = DATEADD(day,365, appdate_dt)
```